# react native android app to react native web app

Tags: reactjs, react-native, web, picker, react-native-web

I am trying to convert my react-native android app into a react-native web app. While doing this I got an error in @react-native-picker\picker.

Failed to compile
./node_modules/@react-native-picker/picker/js/Picker.web.js
SyntaxError: C:\Users\User\Desktop\react-native\TestProject\node_modules@react-native-picker\picker\js\Picker.web.js: Unexpected token (9:12)

```
   7 | 
   8 | import React from 'react';
>  9 | import type {
     |             ^
  10 |   ViewStyleProp,
  11 |   TextStyleProp,
  12 | } from 'react-native/Libraries/StyleSheet/StyleSheet';
```

how can i resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like `Picker.web.js` contains code written with Flow so you'll need to make sure your web project has support for Flow enabled.

---

Since you are using Create React App, you'll need to customize the configuration to enable Babel for packages inside of `node_modules`:

1. Install `customize-cra` and `react-app-rewired`:

```
npm install --save-dev customize-cra react-app-rewired
```

2. Follow the steps to complete the installation of `react-app-rewired`: https://github.com/timarney/react-app-rewired#how-to-rewire-your-create-react-app-project
3. Configure Babel include for `node_modules/@react-native-picker/picker`:

```
// config-overrides.js

const path = require('path');
const {
    babelInclude,
    override,
} = require('customize-cra');

module.exports = override(
    babelInclude([
        path.resolve('src'),
        path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/@react-native-picker/picker'),
    ]),
);
```

Comment: can you guide me how to do that?

Comment: The Flow docs has some [installation instructions](https://flow.org/en/docs/install/) and some other related answers are: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47165650/2089625 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/62481489/2089625

Comment: I tried but still getting the same error.

Comment: @Shivam If you're able to include an example repo in the question that could help find the issue.

Comment: @Shivam I've added instructions for Create React App now.

Comment: I have done all the steps given above now I am getting   `./node_modules/@react-native-picker/picker/js/PickerIOS.js
Attempted import error: 'UnimplementedView' is not exported from 'react-native'.` and  `./node_modules/@react-native-picker/picker/js/Picker.web.js
Attempted import error: 'createElement' is not exported from 'react-native'.`

Comment: @Shivam You should try an older version: `"@react-native-picker/picker": "1.9.5"`, or an older version of `react-native-web` since it looks like the latest version of both are not compatible with each other.

Comment: `./node_modules/@react-native-picker/picker/js/Picker.web.js Attempted import error: 'createElement' is not exported from 'react-native'` this error still showing

Comment: @Shivam I'm not sure you can file a new issue on https://github.com/react-native-picker/picker/issues or ask another question on Stack Overflow

Comment: @RajeshMarotu no